# What would Canada's larger lakes (Bear, Great Slave, Winnipeg, and Athabasca) look like without glaciation?

Tags: plate-tectonics, lakes, continental-rifting

Canada's larger lakes (minus the "Great Lakes" that it shares with the USA) sit on the edge of the Canadian Shield (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TmSP02zPaI). On the other side of the basin, formed as a result, sits the American Cordillera which is already prime lake forming area. This plus their size and shape implies that like the Great Lakes, they have an origin beyond glaciation.

Specifically, Great Slave Lake sits upon the Precambrian Great Slave Lake shear zone, so shouldn't much of it should still exist even without glaciation?

Which other large lakes would still exist without glaciation, instead caused by geological features?  And how would the mentioned lakes (and any other similar Canadian lakes with origins beyond glaciation) look if Canada never glaciated? Or at the very least, what features do they show that are not the result of glaciation?.